# Why accumulate Cloud Firestore doc.id?

Tags: javascript, object, properties, google-cloud-firestore

I stored some data using `db.collection("articles").doc();` and update it using  `db.collection("articles").doc(postData.articleId).update(postData);`. But creating new article next time, the `postData.articleId` is accumulated.

First, I create a doc, then update data in real time using socket.io. but I create another doc later, postData.id was accumulated.

```
var doc = db.collection("articles").doc();
var postData = {
    author: user.email,
    articleId: doc.id,
    currentTime: new Date()
}
doc.set(postData);

--- get data from client code here (using socket) ---

db.collection("articles").doc(postData.articleId).update(postData); /*Update Data to postData.id.*/
```

The expected result is not accumulation postData.id when new data added.

(For more info: https://github.com/officialmansu/opinion-express/tree/develop)

Comment: What do you mean through "accumulated"?

Comment: When I create a new doc and another doc later, it is updated with the doc I created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The `update()` method of Cloud Firestore is specifically meant to provide partial updates (sometimes also known as patches) to an existing document.

If you want to instead replace all existing data of the document, use `set()`. So:

```
db.collection("articles").doc(postData.articleId).set(postData);
```

Comment: I have already created a new doc with doc.set(postData). Then, update the data automatically by listening to the data with the socket. However, the previous id value is accumulated in the current postData.articleId value, which updates multiple docs.

Comment: Your use of the word "accumulated" is hard to me (and others) to understand. Can you show the code you run, the document you start with, the document you have after that code, and the document you are looking to get?

Comment: the "accumulated" means the postData.articleId was piled up like snowball whenever I create a doc. if you want to check my code, visit my [git repo](https://github.com/officialmansu/opinion-express/tree/develop)->routes->index.js(106~125line)